# Why is AbstractBaseUser placed in a separate module?

Tags: python, django

I'm enthusiastic in learning Django's source to establish my skills from bottom.

In User model, it has [password](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.password) attribute. The model is import with command `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`,

I checked the module [django/models.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py),failed to find `password = models.CharField()`, but eventually found it in [django/base_user.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py)

```
class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
    password = models.CharField(_('password'), max_length=128)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(_('last login'), blank=True, null=True)
```

It's interesting that `AbstractBaseUser` and `BaseUserManager` are encapsulated as a separate module rather than incorporated to `models.py` even though the codes are just 139 lines long.

In `base_user.py`, it claims that

> """
>   This module allows importing AbstractBaseUser even when django.contrib.auth is
>   not in INSTALLED_APPS."""

It's beyond my knowledge to grasp its idea.

What's the benefit to design modules this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git blame` can be a useful tool to answer questions like this.

If you do git blame for the [`base_user.py`](https://github.com/django/django/blame/5008d59a2a8b9df09737fc05c9e343146a348a90/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py), you can see that the comment was added in [this commit](https://github.com/django/django/commit/fe914341c83b37fd6aa8fd85620cf49dd2328ab0), which was part of [ticket 24564](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24564).

As that ticket explained, if you wanted to import `AbstractBaseUser` from `django.contrib.auth.models` you had to add `django.contrib.auth` to `INSTALLED_APPS`. This is because the module contains non-abstract models like `User`.

Therefore it was moved to a separate module, which allows it to be imported without adding `django.contrib.auth` to `INSTALLED_APPS`.